# How to remove a specific empty array from $_SESSION with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have set of arrays with combination of set/unset session value from the previous page. I want to remove the unset value. But I don't know how to remove it because it's have no key to tell which one.

**$array**

```
Array ( 
  [4ltr] => 5 
  [] => 
  [800ml] => 10 
)
```

As you see the 2nd array is empty both key and value. I can thinking of the `empty()` but again, how to tell the script to remove the key with blank value?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I fxxk up. This is easy like shssst.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['ss'] as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
       unset($_SESSION['ss'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with,

```
$_SESSION= array_filter($_SESSION, function($v, $k){ return $v && $k;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
```

You can test below code, [demo](https://eval.in/895066)

```
print_r(array_filter(array('' => '2', '3' =>3), function($v, $k){ return $v && $k;},  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be without assigning the modified data to a variable. It's just a fancy pattern. If you are doing that on every page then you can just write a global function to check.

```
array_walk($data, function($item, $key) use (&$data){
   if(empty($item)){
      unset($data[$key]);
    }
});

print_r($data)
```